# Problems Using Basic Features CKEDITOR

Tags: angular, typescript, ckeditor

I'm having some problems when trying to use some basic features of ckeditor. I'm creating a application that simulate some key presses by a keyboard rendered on browser screen, and I noted that there is no available option within the API that allow me to delete a already inserted character. Like for example when simulating a backspace key.

So, my doubts are mainly:

1- How can I delete characters in editor textarea? I tryed to use setData() with new fresh data, but the cursor is always reseted to the position 0

2- How can I select text from cursor position 'x' to 'y', for example 0 to 3?

3- How can I simulate the keys like, Enter, Space, Backspace, and other special keys?

4- How can I set the cursor position to position 'x'? Like for example, postion 4? Assuming that 0 is the beginning?

Other details
Browser: Chrome
OS: Windows
CKEditor version: 4.8.0

Comment: It's best to ask one question at a time on SO.

Comment: And add the code you attempted to write